# Mover la pantalla hacia un <div id="ancla"> cuando se hacer click sobre un filtro en la tienda

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Tengo una tienda hecha con wordpress y estoy intentado añadir un script o algo que desplace la pagina hacia abajo cuando alguien pulsa en algun filtro, porque los filtros estan muy arriba y quiero que una vez se haga click, la pantlla sola se mueva hasta ese punto.

Mi intencion es hacerlo con javascript porque he visto que esos filtros de tipo `<li>` una vez haces click sobre ellos se convierten en `<li class="checked">`. Pretendo atrapar con `document.getElementsByClassName("checked");`
y hacer que entonces se mueva a una direccion con un enlace interno al punto donde empiezan los articulo de la tienda, donde he insertado un `<div class="ancla">`

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SOes! Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para conocer mejor la temática del sitio y por qué es recomendable proveer de un [mcve] o al menos el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora, te haya funcionado o no

Comment: Por otra parte, si estás en la la página (por ejemplo) `https://.../index.html`, con añadir a la URL el ancla es suficiente: `https://.../index.html#ancla`

Answer (score -1):

Existe una forma bastante simple de hacerlo solo con html, a una etiqueta `<a></a>` puedes añadirle un `href` para que al hacer click este se desplace hacia la ubicación donde esta el elemento.

Aqui un ejemplo de hacerlo en HTML:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_href_anchor

La documentación correspondiente:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash

De igual forma funciona en javascript. Puedes utilizar la propiedad `window.location.hash` para redirecionar la pagina al elemento deseado.

Puedes encontrar un ejemplo aquí
http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ntr5b/

EDIT 1: Gracias a los comentarios por orientarme con la documentación de mozilla, ahi agregue los 2 links que faltaban

Comment: Por favor considera agregar el ejemplo aquí con formato de snnipet, por otro lado existen fuentes de mas calidad para referenciar como: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a

Comment: Si, tienes razón, aunque personalmente me gusta mas w3school al ser mas interactivo. Pero ciertamente tienes razón, lo editare ahora.